# Вызов функции из класса по ссылке на класс

Tags: java, android, классы

Есть MainActivity и класс API.

При запуске activity отправляется запрос к серверу. После отправки запроса нужно вернуть результат в функцию onRequestEnd в MainActivity.

В API при инициализации класса отдается класс и контекст MainActivity.

Как можно вызвать onRequestEnd() из API, учитывая то, что к API можно будет обращаться так же из разных activity и всегда возвращать результат в onRequestEnd()?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        API API = new API(MainActivity.class, MainActivity.this);
        API.request("getStartData");
    }

    public void onRequestEnd(String result) {
         showToast("request end");
    }

    void showToast(final String text) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class API {
    private static Context context = null;
    private static Class callbackClass = null;

    public API(Class cls, Context cntxt){
        context = cntxt;
        callbackClass = cls;
    }

    public void request(String method) {
        new Request().execute(method);
    }

    public class Request extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //запрос к api
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // вызов MainActivity.onRequestEnd
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface Callback {
    void onRequestEnd(String result);
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        API api = new API(this);
        api.setCallback(this);
        api.request("getStartData");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestEnd(String result) {
         showToast("request end");
    }

    ...
}

public class API {

    private static Callback callback;

    public void setCallback(Callback callback){
    this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        callback.onRequestEnd(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Пример вызова в MainActivity.onCreate() можно?

Comment: Можно, там одну строчку дописать в вашем коде и все по сути.